# Java.lang.NullPointerException in my own shuffle method while using random numbers in Java?

Tags: java, random, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to implement a shuffle method to shuffle cards in a deck array class.

Here's the code:

```
public void shuffle()
{
    Card holderCard = new Card();
    for (int x = 0; x < 1000; x++)
    {
        spot1 = rnd.nextInt(52);<<<<<<<
        spot2 = rnd.nextInt(52);

        holderCard = deck[spot1];
        deck[spot1] = deck[spot2];
        deck[spot2] = holderCard;
    }
}
```

Every time I run the program and get to the shuffle method, I get a `java.lang.NullPointerException` on the line with <<<<<<.

I don't really know why or how, but this method is just supposed to change the position of cards in the array.

Answer (score 3):

You are supposed to initialize the `rnd` variable before using it:

```
Random rnd = new Random ();
```

Comment: That did it something weird happened at the top where i initialized it Thank you

Answer (score 0):

May be you have just declared variable `rnd` and not initialize it like

```
 Random rnd = new Random ();
```